# Azure storage table records filtering advice

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

Imaging something like a blog posting system, built using Azure Storage Table.
A user posts a message and the database records user's Region, City and Language along with it.

After that, a user is able to browse all other user's posts and able to filter them by any combination of Region, City and Language. Or neither and see all of them.

I see several solutions:

1. Put each message in 8 different partitions with combinations of Region-City-Language (pros: lightning fast point queries on read; cons: 8 transactions per message on write).
2. Put each message in 4 different partitions with combinations of Region-City and an ability to do partition scan to filter by languages (pros: less transactions than (1); cons: partition scan, 4 transactions per message).
3. Put each message in partitions, based on user's ID (pros: single transaction per message; cons: slow table scan and partition scan after that).

The way i see it:

1. Fast reads, slow (and perhaps costly) writes.
2. Balanced reads/writes/cost.
3. Fast writes, slow (but cheap) reads.

By "cost/cheap" i mean pricing based on transactions (not space).
And by "balanced" i mean just among these variants.

Thought about using index tables, but can't see how they help here.
So the question is, perhaps there is another, better way?

Comment: This is really opinion-soliciting and broad - there's no right answer. You'll need to benchmark and choose the right combination for your particular app. Not sure what you mean by "index tables" though (maybe you're referring to additional storage tables, with specific indexed property as partition/row key?).

Comment: Yes. Index table is something like you've described. I was asking if there are any other possible solutions to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to go with a variation of (1).

The difference is that i won't be storing ALL of combinations for Region-Location-Language. Instead i decided to store only uniques:

```
Table: FiltersByRegion
----------------------
Partition:  Region
Row:        Location.Language
Prop:       Message
```

---

```
Table: FiltersByRegionPlace
---------------------------
Partition:  Region.Location
Row:        Language
Prop:       Message
```

---

```
Table: FiltersByRegionLanguage
------------------------------
Partition:  Region.Language
Row:        Location
Prop:       Message
```

---

```
Table: FiltersByLanguage
------------------------
Partition:  Language
Row:        Region.Location
Prop:       Message
```

---

Because of the fact that i'm storing only uniques there won't be a lot of transactions per every post. Only those, that are not already present in database.

In other words, if there are a lot of posts from the same region-location-language, filter tables won't be updated and transactions won't be spent. Tests for uniques could use Redis to speed things a bit.

Filtering is now only a matter of picking the right table.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on your scenarios and read/write pattern. You might want to consider some aspects:

1. Design for how the records will be queried. Putting them into a "Region-City-Language" partition with message ID as entity data may help in your fast query.
2. Each message may have a unique message ID and ID-Message mappings are saved in other tables, then every time you only need to update one table when a message is updated and the message ID referenced in other tables keeps unchanged.
3. Leverage ParitionKey and RowKey in your table design and query entities with both keys. For instance: "Region-City-Language" as partition keys and "User" as row keys.
4. Consider storing duplicate copies of entities for query scenarios. For example, if you have heavy users based and language based queries, you may consider have two tables with "user" and "language" as keys respectively.

Please also refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-table-design-guide/ for a full guide.